# Can I adress a element and a child without retyping the parent in scss?

Tags: sass, css-selectors

Let's assume our html looks something like this:

```
<a>
    <span class="title">Foo</span>
    <span class="black-color-important">Bar</span>
    Baz
</a>
```

Let's say `.black-color-important` stays always black. `.title` has a color assigned.

On hover, the normal text in the link and the title should switch colors to the `$primary-color`.

My SCSS for it looks like this:

```
a:hover, a:hover .title {
    color: $primary-color;
}
```

Is there a better way? Or with other words is there a way, that I don't have to retype `a:hover`?

(If it would help, I don't care if it's `a:hover > .title` or `a:hover .title` in my case the `.title` would always be a direct child, but I tried to keep the question as open as possible)

Note: this is just an abstract example, not the real use case for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the state of child element depends of its parent state, than you can't write styles without retyping the parent in scss.

But if you want to set a regular styles to a child, you can use [BEM](https://bem.info) methodology and don't retype parent name.

```
div.parent
    div.parent__child

.parent {}
.parent__child {}
```